# TransferManager.UploadAsync is taking extremely long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am tying to upload a file to a blobstorage in azure. The upload works fine with small files but when the file gets bigger (like 30mb) it gets extremely slow. I already tried different approaches but didn't get any better results.

When I'm running the webapp local it takes like 5 minutes to upload and on the azure webapp I'm not getting any result (probably the process is getting killed)

So here is my code for uploading the stuff:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/upload")]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!Request.HasFormContentType)
        return BadRequest();
    var form = Request.Form;
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration["CloudStorage:Account"]);
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("files");
    for (int i = 0; i < form.Files.Count(); i++)
    {
        using (var readStream = form.Files[i].OpenReadStream())
        {
            String blobname = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobname);
            TransferManager.Configurations.ParallelOperations = 64;
            SingleTransferContext context = new SingleTransferContext
            {
                ProgressHandler =
                new Progress<TransferStatus>(
                progress => { Console.WriteLine("{1} Bytes uploaded: {0}", progress.BytesTransferred, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")); })
            };

            // I tryed this 2 options:
            TransferManager.UploadAsync(readStream, blockBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

            //and:
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + blobname))
            {
                readStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                readStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
            TransferManager.UploadAsync(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + blobname, blockBlob, null, context, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
            System.IO.File.Delete(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + blobname);
        }
    }
    return OK();
}
```

And this is my console output:

```
14:03:34 Bytes uploaded: 0
14:03:34 Bytes uploaded: 0
14:03:34 Bytes uploaded: 0
14:03:34 Bytes uploaded: 0
Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.0\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.    
The thread 13984 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 5220 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 9968 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 10744 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 13488 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 9460 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
14:05:54 Bytes uploaded: 1540505
The thread 792 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
14:07:36 Bytes uploaded: 5734809
14:07:36 Bytes uploaded: 9929113
14:07:38 Bytes uploaded: 14123417
14:07:43 Bytes uploaded: 18317721
14:07:53 Bytes uploaded: 22512025
14:07:54 Bytes uploaded: 26706329
14:08:10 Bytes uploaded: 30900633
14:08:13 Bytes uploaded: 35094937
14:08:14 Bytes uploaded: 35094937
```

So has anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Have you followed the best practice mentioned here? https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#best-practice

Comment: I have added these improvements, but it does not change anything. But I tried to upload the same file over the azure storage explorer and it also needed this long (like 10 minutes for 30 MB). Then I tried different servers  at different locations and with different settings.(North and West Europe && LRS/RA-GRS) But it also didn't affect anything. For files smaller than 10mb the upload works completely fine.